# multiple/optional segues from UITableViewController tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have seen this topic on here but none of the solutions clicked or worked for me.
I have a ***UITableViewController***,(call it **myUITableViewController**) and the requirements are such that if the user selects the one of the first three rows from **myUITableViewController**, they will be brought to **theFirstViewController**, but if they had chosen any rows *above* three they will be brought to **theSecondViewController**.  I am using storyboards which do not seem to allow multiple segues off a single tableview cell.
However, I can add multiple segue's directly from **myUITableViewController** but then I am struggling with the proper segue code and have not found a proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to not use segues directly from IB but instead use `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and manually call them from code whenever they select a row in the table.

You should setup the segues from the tableview itself to the destinations, and not specific elements from within the table.

Something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
    NSString *identifierOfSegueToCall;
    if (indexPath.row < 3) {
        identifierOfSegueToCall = @"theFirstViewControllerSegueIdentifier";
    } else {
        identifierOfSegueToCall = @"theSecondViewControllerSegueIdentifier";
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:identifierOfSegueToCall sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not there.  Do I still use storyboard to 'push' from the ViewController to the others?  That does not seem to work.

Comment: Yes, and you need to name the segues by clicking on them and setting the Identifier.  Make sure that you use the same values for the identifier and the name of the segue.  (I'll update the code to use the correct naming convention for the Identifier).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something...The NSString above is called identifierOfSegueToCall then there is a var called nameOfSegueToCall...is this intentional?  Also, are there any other segue functions in the view controller such as prepareForSegue?  Or just this one call?  Rick

Comment: Appreciate this help....still not working.  Usually I set         self.nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController; in - (void)prepareForSegue.  Your code references the segue name but not the controller.  How do I reference both?

Comment: When you use performSegueWithIdentifier you don't need the actual view controller.  It automatically loads the segue with the given identifier from the storyboard that the current viewController was loaded from.

Comment: Almost there but still has problems.....In didSelectRowAtIndexPath I also set up my annotations for the subsequent mapviewcontroller.  ([self.mapViewController setAnnotations:myAttributes];)   However these settings do not 'take' when using this method you have suggested.  (It goes to the next view but there is an empty map, the settings did not go through).  It seems the navigation works but not the setting of data in the next controller.  They do work with prepareForSegue....but not with performSegueWithIdentifier....  Any ideas?

Comment: prepareForSegue should still be called and you can do your setup there.

Comment: I moved my setup from didSelectRowAtIndexPath to prepareForSegue and added global var to track the row selected in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, then reference that var in prepareForSegue to set the appropriate data (not sure I need that extra var but it works).  Working - THANK YOU.  Rick